# How to filter tableview data on textfield editing - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I created tableview using array and one textfield. **On textfield editing tableview data will be sort and filter according to textfield input.** In case of table view has a data about states, If I input 'A' in textfield, all tableview data will be sort and display all state names starting with alphabet 'A'. Please tell me logic for this.

Comment: You can take help of Predicate to filter out the result and then reload your table.
NB: Keep two array one will contain all data, other will hold filtered data from the first array. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Youtube video :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgNRMcCWJhU&list=PLt2cCXacqzgfUAjHYnZ9rrPkih4NzAV4E&index=25

and site link may solve your problem.
http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/

you just need to keep reloading table and put code in while editing function.

For example :

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = true
    tblSearchResults.reloadData()
}



func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text

    // Filter the data array and get only those countries that match the search text.
    filteredArray = dataArray.filter({ (country) -> Bool in
        let countryText: NSString = country

        return (countryText.rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch).location) != NSNotFound
    })

    // Reload the tableview.
    tblSearchResults.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use **UISearchController** which has lots of features and what you are asking now is so simple if you use this.
So please go for UISearchController.

[UISearchController tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) will be helpful for you.